# how to validate if there are 3 checkbox selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox

I am currently using the following [jQuery validation engine.](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine). And I wanted to have 3 different checkboxes at minimum selected and the html looks like this:

```
<fieldset class="group" id="tajirr_user_complete_registration_wanita">
           <legend><label class="required">Wanita</label></legend>
           <ul class="checkbox">
              <li><input type="checkbox" class="validate[minCheckbox[3], maxCheckbox[5]]" data-prompt-position="topLeft:0,-30" id="tajirr_user_complete_registration_wanita_0" name="tajirr_user_complete_registration[wanita][]" value="10"><label for="tajirr_user_complete_registration_wanita_0">Atasan &amp; Bawahan</label></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" class="validate[minCheckbox[3], maxCheckbox[5]]" data-prompt-position="topLeft:0,-30" id="tajirr_user_complete_registration_wanita_1" name="tajirr_user_complete_registration[wanita][]" value="11"><label for="tajirr_user_complete_registration_wanita_1">Dress</label></li>
           </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="group" id="tajirr_user_complete_registration_pria">
       <legend><label class="required">Pria</label></legend>
       <ul class="checkbox">
          <li><input type="checkbox" class="validate[minCheckbox[3], maxCheckbox[5]]" data-prompt-position="topLeft:0,-30" id="tajirr_user_complete_registration_pria_0" name="tajirr_user_complete_registration[pria][]" value="19"><label for="tajirr_user_complete_registration_pria_0">Atasan &amp; Bawahan</label></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" class="validate[minCheckbox[3], maxCheckbox[5]]" data-prompt-position="topLeft:0,-30" id="tajirr_user_complete_registration_pria_1" name="tajirr_user_complete_registration[pria][]" value="21"><label for="tajirr_user_complete_registration_pria_1">Sepatu</label></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" class="validate[minCheckbox[3], maxCheckbox[5]]" data-prompt-position="topLeft:0,-30" id="tajirr_user_complete_registration_pria_2" name="tajirr_user_complete_registration[pria][]" value="22"><label for="tajirr_user_complete_registration_pria_2">Batik</label></li>
       </ul>
</fieldset>
```

I wanted to validate on the form such that there are at minimum 3 checkboxes are selected. However the above didn't work because `minCheckbox` validates based on the `name`attribute, which there are two in this form:`tajirr_user_complete_registration[pria][]` and the other one had `tajirr_user_complete_registration[wanita][]`. I can change the name so that it works just fine, however it breaks other stuff. How can I make this so that it validates across the whole form?

Comment: Do mind if the validation is done manually?  So out of the five check boxes here you want at least 3 of them to be checked?

Comment: Yes out of the 5 I want 3 to be checked. And define what is manual? I prefer to be using this validationEngine that I am already using

Comment: Yeah i'm not familiar with the validationEngine so can't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want at least 3 of 5 to be checked, you can do it like this. No need for validation:
http://jsfiddle.net/nSgC8/

```
function check(){
var checked=0;
    $( "input:checkbox" ).each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
        checked++;
        }
});
    if(checked>2){
    alert('Ok!');
    }
    else{
    alert('At least 3 checkboxes need to be selected!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validator, you can use something like this, on the `onsubmit` event of the `<form>`:

```
if ($("input:checked").length > 2)
    // Proceed
else
    // Alert
```

I used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        if ($("input:checked").length > 2)
            alert("Thanks for the answer!");
        else
            alert("Select min 3!!!");
        return false;
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/SFF4P/

Answer (score 0):

```
var checked_count = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
alert(checked_count + " checkboxes are checked");
```